# Selenium Grid :Could not start Selenium Session:Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup

Tags: selenium-grid

When I run ant targets through Selenium grid, I'm able to launch all targets in parallel. If I close any of the Firefox session before completion of execution. I get:

```
ERROR Server Exception: sessionId fc89c194951a4790bce8418dac7d5ceb doesn't exist;
     perhaps this session was already stopped?
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:262)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getStringArray(HttpCommandProcessor.java:271)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.getAllWindowTitles(DefaultSelenium.java:567)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.util.URLTestContext.seleniumStart(URLTestContext.java:232)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.util.URLTestContext.CommonLogin(URLTestContext.java:66)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.main.AutomationFileSequence.main(AutomationFileSequence.java:86)
     [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.util.URLTestContext.CommonLogin(URLTestContext.java:78)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.main.AutomationFileSequence.main(AutomationFileSequence.java:86)
     [java] com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException:
           org%2Eopenqa%2Egrid%2Ecommon%2Eexception%2EGridException%3A+Session+
           %5Bfc89c194951a4790bce8418dac7d5ceb%5D+not+available+%2D+%5Bext%2E+
           key+1a83ce8d23284bc0ae57545c85f93edf%2C+ext%2E+key+
           9de7dcbcdc29438db917d22773cf3598%5D
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:168)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:104)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:86)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.stop(HttpCommandProcessor.java:252)
     [java]  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.stop(DefaultSelenium.java:112)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.util.URLTestContext.stop(URLTestContext.java:268)
     [java]  at com.operative.qa.automation.main.AutomationFileSequence.main(AutomationFileSequence.java:114)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Is there a way to stop the Selenium session. Sometimes, if I manually close Firefox browser to stop execution and shut down server. Still, the execution continues and mark all test cases as fail. How to get rid of this?

I'm using: Selenium RC with grid 2

Comment: Why do you want to stop the session during execution? And are you executing this using a scheduled process (like Jenkins/Hudson) or through IDE (Eclipse etc)

Comment: We are executing 3 modules in parallel .Triggering it from eclipse. If suppose, i checked-in wrong tenant name,i need to stop the execution and re launch , To stop that,i will stop using eclipse stop(red button),which stops showing console logs ,but session will continue to run.If i close the browser, still session continues, after that, if i shutdown the hub which launches all these 3 modules parallel, still the session continues and marks all 500 testcases of these 3 modules as **failed**.To overcome this, i m doing, machine re boot all the time, so that i can stop execution.

Comment: Where do you see this failed report? Are you using any framework like testNG or jUnit? By shutting down grid, you are only killing the process which runs the tests. You seem to still have the process which sends the commands to hub running.

Comment: We are not using testNG or Junit, We have our keyword driven framework in place.The report will be published after each testcase gets over. Ther is one file called URLTestContext which has stop server command , as shown in above log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing browsers doesn't stop execution. You have to stop it with whatever program you use for test starting or with pleaseStop() from RunNotifier.

Comment: Even if i stop our suitelauncher java class, session doesn't stop,just the console will end. How to use RunNotifier?

Comment: Well to stop your testrun I would need to know how you started it (with which program?) and a bit of code would be helpful

Comment: private static void seleniumStart() {
  
  proc = new HttpCommandProcessor("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://xxxxx.com:8080/xxxxe");
  selenium = new DefaultSelenium(proc);
  selenium.start();
  try {
  selenium.open(AutomationConfig.APPLICATIONURL);

Comment: To be honest I never use ant for unit testing because I wrote my own IDE for testing (which you don't usually need because theres eclipse & co). So I don't know how to stop an ant run if you run one. Maybe you can figure that out yourself or start your tests in an IDE like eclipse where you can easily start & stop your testruns. If you build your own runner with your own RunNotifier (which is basically your own IDE for unit testing) you can use pleaseStop() on the RunNotifier, to stop the test run. This is time consuming, if you wan't to you can hv a look: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But our framework doesn't use junit at all.But, my problem is sometimes hub says "cannot find session in the registry".. How to get rid of this

Comment: sorry my knowledge ends here.

Answer (score 0):

I stop the java.exe process from task manager .hence session gets killed .